# Difference between the sums of even digits and odd digits in a number

Tags: python

I am trying to find the difference between the sum of the even digits and odd digits in a number. My code only works for just one case which is 412 but it doesnt work for numbers such as 23 and 1203.
I dont know why. Here is my code

```
def digitS(n):
    even = 0
    odd = 0
    while (n!=0):
        for i in range(n):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                even = even + (n%10)
            else:
                odd = odd + (n%10)
            n//=10

    return even - odd
n = 412
print(digitS(n))
```

Comment: Note that there's no reason for needing `n` loops - you only will have as many steps as you have digits, and your `while` loop should take care of that.

Comment: I think there's a typo in the function name. should it be digit instead of digitS?

Comment: @jane , avoid complicating your code with so much mathematical notation. Turn the integer to a string, iterate over it and you'll get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discard for loop.

```
def digitS(n):
    even = 0
    odd = 0
    while (n!=0):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            even += (n%10)
        else:
            odd += (n%10)
        n//=10

return even - odd
n = 412
print(digitS(n))
```

Comment: This worked after indenting line 11(return even -odd). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is kinda obscure to me, that you want to find the difference between odd and even digits or the difference between odd and even positions?

BTW, I assumed you want to count the former -- your code implementing the latter with some issues in designing.

```
def digit(n):
   even = 0
   odd = 0
   while (n != 0):
       r = n % 10
       if r % 2 == 0:
          even = even + r
       else:
          odd = odd + r
       n //= 10

   return even - odd


n = 412
print(digit(int(n)))
```

and a more concise response with the aid of strings!

```
def digit(n):
   even = [int(i) if int(i) % 2 == 0 else 0 for i in str(n)]
   odd = [int(i) if int(i) % 2 else 0 for i in str(n)]
   return sum(even) - sum(odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some edits to your code below. What you have attempted is perfectly right, but the for loop is an obstruction and should be removed. Also, from what I understood, you wanted the `difference` between the odd and even digit sums. For that, you must return the absolute value of `even - odd`.

```py
def digits(n):
    even = 0
    odd = 0

    while (n!=0):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            even += (n%10)
        else:
            odd += (n%10)
        n //= 10

    return abs(even - odd)

print(digits(412)) # 5
print(digits(23)) # 1
```

Comment: This checks if the number is even or odd and not just the digits

Comment: @Sandsten No, I am doing the same thing as the accepted answer, I had posted my answer first, and I also have an explanation....

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need `for` in 5th line, as you only want to iterate digits instead of whole range of numbers. So for example if number is 1203 you want to check 1, 2, 0 and 3, instead of 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 1201, 1202. Also checking digits is already handled in `while(n!=0): n//=10`, so `for` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your input to a string, iterate over the elements one by one, check if they are odd or even by turning them to integers et Voila!

```
def digit(n):
    even = 0
    odd = 0
    string = str(n)
    for i in string:
        if int(i) % 2 == 0:
            even += int(i)
        else:
            odd += int(i)
    return even - odd
n = 282
print(digit(n)) #12
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the for loop is meant to do. But here's an example of what you could do instead. Discard the for loop and go through each digit until n == 0.

```py
def digit(n):
    even = 0 # Sum of even numbers
    odd = 0 # Sum of odd numbers
    while (n!=0):
        digit = n%10 # Get the right most digit of the number
        if digit % 2 == 0: # Check if the digit is even or odd
            even = even + digit
        else:
            odd = odd + digit
        n//=10 # Remove the digit from the number

    return even - odd
n = 412
print(digit(n))
```